# maven multi module build with a shared utility project

Tags: java, maven

Hi I am converting a ear project to Maven. Below is the structure

-projA-ear

-projA-static

-projA-web

-shared-util

The shared util is shared by multiple *unrelated* projects handled by our team. Currently my deployment assembly is handled by eclipse and the shared-util.jar is automatically built inside the projA-web.war's *WEB-INF/lib* directory

When I convert my setup to Maven project, I am reading that I need multi module aggregator setup, and need to define shared-util as a module, and then define the aggregator POM as the parent to my modules. The problem is I cannot define projA-mvn as parent in the shared-util project as the other projects would be using it too as a module(when they decide to move to maven). Can someone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make shared-util as a separate standalone Maven project.

2) Put projA-ear, projA-web and projA-static under a separate parent Maven project.

3) Declare shared-util jar as a dependency in your projA-web pom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that, but if I do that, when I build projA, it does not automatically build shared-util.

Comment: It does not. One option is to put both parent of projA and shared-util  under yet another parent maven project. That is totally normal setup.